# Is there any posible way to write click event for mat-icon inside mat form field (matprefix or matsuffix)?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, mat-form-field

I have a mat-form-field and I used a custom mat-icon inside that mat-form-field as a matprefix. Now I want to write a click method for that matprefix icon. Is there any posibility? I try wrote click method but it iis not working

```
 <mat-form-field floatLabel="never" >         
      <mat-icon  (click)="clicking()"  matPrefix class="formula-icon" svgIcon="lo-formula"
      *ngIf="item[displayedColumn]?.formula != undefined && item[displayedColumn].lock == 'off'">
    </mat-icon>
     <input [value]=currentFocusValue
        autocomplete="off">
    </mat-form-field>
```

[image: mat-form-field with mat-prefix]

Answer (score 0):

You can use a mat-icon-button instead:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput type="text" value="test" #input>
  <button mat-button 
          *ngIf=item[displayedColumn]?.formula != undefined && item[displayedColumn].lock == 'off'"
          matPrefix
          mat-icon-button
          class="formula-icon" svgIcon="lo-formula"
          (click)="clicking($event,input)">
    <mat-icon>close</mat-icon>
  </button>
</mat-form-field>

clicking(evt: MouseEvent, input: HTMLInputElement) {
input.value = '';
  // avoids focusing the input after clicking on the close button
  evt.stopPropagation();
}
```